# CountDownLatch in Android locking thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-volley, countdownlatch

I've just started playing around with `CountDownLatch` in my Android app. Currently I am trying to make two `Volley` requests to my api, and wait until the data has been retrieved and stored before continuing with thread execution.

This is a sample of my code:

```
    // new CountDownLatch for 2 requests
    final CountDownLatch allDoneSignal = new CountDownLatch(2);

    transactions.getResourcesForRealm(Contact.class, "", new ICallBack<Contact>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(ArrayList<Contact> resources, String resourceId) {
            transactions.createRealmObject(resources, Contact.class);

            allDoneSignal.countDown();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFail(ArrayList<Contact> resources) {

        }
    });

    transactions.getResourcesForRealm(Meeting.class, "", new ICallBack<Meeting>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(ArrayList<Meeting> resources, String resourceId) {
            transactions.createRealmObject(resources, Meeting.class);

            allDoneSignal.countDown();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFail(ArrayList<Meeting> resources) {

        }
    });

    try {
        allDoneSignal.await();
        // continue executing code
        // ...
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**The issue is that it doesn't seem to "complete" the countdown and therefore freezes because the latch is never released**. I have confirmed that the API requests are working and the `onSuccess` callback is hit successfully, but the thread hangs.

**UPDATE**
I've just noticed that with the `CountDownLatch` set to 0, it hits `onSuccess`, but when I set it to anything greater than 0, it freezes and `onSuccess` is never called. Seems like something's funky with the threading.

Comment: I may be wrong but for thread and value related issue please check `Volatile variable` concept.

Comment: That should work as expected - can you maybe log something just before calling countDown to make sure that the method is really called?

Comment: @PradeepKumarKushwaha There is no need for volatile here, the latch already gives sufficient synchronization guarantees.

Comment: I will attempt to `Log.wtf` this...

Comment: Also you say "new countdownlatch for 2 requests" - maybe double check that the `allDoneSignal` variable is the same in the three places (if the code is exactly like you posted in a single method then it obviously is)...

Comment: can you provide the entire code and the code of getResourcesForRealm?

Answer (score 6):

Your code is too error prone, you need to call `countDown()` in a finally block and call it also in `onFail` otherwise in case of failure your application will freeze for ever. So your code should rather be something like:

```
transactions.getResourcesForRealm(Contact.class, "", new ICallBack<Contact>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(ArrayList<Contact> resources, String resourceId) {
        try {
            transactions.createRealmObject(resources, Contact.class);
        } finally {
            allDoneSignal.countDown();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFail(ArrayList<Contact> resources) {
        allDoneSignal.countDown();
    }
});

transactions.getResourcesForRealm(Meeting.class, "", new ICallBack<Meeting>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(ArrayList<Meeting> resources, String resourceId) {
        try {
            transactions.createRealmObject(resources, Meeting.class);
        } finally {
            allDoneSignal.countDown();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFail(ArrayList<Meeting> resources) {
        allDoneSignal.countDown();
    }
});
```

Comment: While this is a good advice in general, it doesn't answer the question, the question is a very bad and requires assumption that you don't have to do.

Comment: @SleimanJneidi yes I know but we all know that CountDownLatch works well so if the program freezes it is because countDown() is not called twice as expected for some reason so I simply provide a way to make sure that it is called even in case of failure

Comment: Thanks for the good error handling, I've implemented this and i'm trying to figure out why it doesn't hit `countDown()`

Comment: @barnacle.m I believe that it means that onSuccess is called by the calling thread, try to print the value of Thread.currentThread()

Comment: I have tried passing the latch in as a parameter for the async request and counting down in the new thread. It still just hangs.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for the late answer, but if it's still any help to anyone:

You need to do the ".await" in a separate thread because it blocks the current thread.

Example:

```
final Handler mainThreadHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        allDoneSignal.await();
        mainThreadHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            doSomethingWhenAllDone();
        });
}
}).start()
```

Comment: hello. Is this a working solution?