# How to make Unit test code for android using OkHttp3 Post request?

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, post, okhttp

I have implemented a method - postData inside the LoginService class like below-

```
public class LoginService {


private String responsePost = "";
private String response_status;
private Context context;

String logInResponse;
private String account_token = "";

public LoginService(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}


public void postData(String url, final String email, String password) {


    MediaType JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("email", "" + email);
    params.put("password", "" + password);

    JSONObject parameter = new JSONObject(params);
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, parameter.toString());
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url+"login")
            .post(body)
            .addHeader("content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
            .build();

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {


            responsePost = response.code()+"";
            Log.e("###response_code:", responsePost);

            if(responsePost.equals("200"))
            {

                logInResponse="logged In";

                account_token = response.headers().get("Authorization");

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences("Profile_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                editor.putString("account_id", account_token);
                editor.putString("email", email);
                editor.apply();

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class);

                context.startActivity(intent);
            }

            else
            {
                ((Activity)context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //show the response body
                        Toast.makeText(context,"Incorrent Email or Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

            }


        }

    });



}
```

}

The purpose of this method is to get right response code after posting the email and password inside the body. if the response code is matched then then log in will be successful, otherwise not.
Now, I wrote a test class for testing the postData method like below-

```
public class LoginServiceTest {

private String responsePost = "";

@Test
public void postData() throws Exception {

    MediaType JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("email", "a@a.a");
    params.put("password", "123456");

    JSONObject parameter = new JSONObject(params);
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, parameter.toString());
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("...")
            .post(body)
            .addHeader("content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
            .build();

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {

            responsePost = response.code()+"";

        }

    });


    assertEquals(responsePost, "200");

}
```

}

But when I run the test code, then the test fails showing following error-

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: 
Expected :
Actual   :200
<Click to see difference>
```

Can Anyone help me to suggest how I can write test code for checking whether the response code is right or not ?

Comment: You should make your test wait until the onResponse() method is called and then check the response. You can use Thread.sleep(milliseconds) or using CountDownLatch, take a look here to understand how: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38694614/countdownlatch-in-android-locking-thread

Comment: well, I am not understanding how to implement these methods you mentioned. will you please write how I can implement those on my code.

Comment: add Thread.sleep(30000) after the newCall method. Move your assertEquals inside the onResponse callback

Comment: I did try this before but I am not getting sleep method when I called it inside newCall method.

Comment: You don't have to call Thread.sleep inside the new call method, you have to call it AFTER the new call method in order to wait for the response inside the callback